# Ninja Forms - add a field programmatically to a form

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm searching for hours to get an answer to this simple question but I'm not able to get any information about this. The ninja form will be used to book a room in a hotel. I have a custom post type "Rooms" that holds the data for the room (acf), eg. single or double room, equipment features, etc. I want to be able to create a bunch of form elements (e.g. a select for single or double room) dynamically out of the data of the different rooms (custom post type fields) and add the dynamically created fields to an existing ninja form.

I can't use placeholder fields in the form and replace the values because the number of different rooms is not always the same. If I add a new room (as a new content page) the form should automatically list that new room without touching the form builder.

Getting the room values is no problem, I just can't find any documentation for adding custom generated fields to an existing form.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Same question here.
Hope to find a solution for this feature soon

Comment: Figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You use this filter to add options to a form:

https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/dynamic-list-fields/

I have my fields being added dynamically, however I'm not seeing them being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to dynamically add fields to a NF form. There are a lot of things that go into validation, saving, loading, etc., so I couldn't find anything on it either. What I did instead was:

- Create fields to hold onto the dynamic values (I used select dropdown fields). I imagine you will want a field for each room feature (beds, guests, etc.).
- Use the filter `ninja_forms_render_options` to display options in a select dropdown field, pulling dynamic values from custom fields of the room.

Here is an example using `ninja_forms_render_options` that displays all rooms:

```php
add_filter('ninja_forms_render_options', function($options, $settings) {
    // Get rooms
    $rooms = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'room',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));

    $opts = array();
    if($rooms) {
        // Goal here is to get the ID (value) and 
        // name of the room (option label)
        foreach($rooms as $room) {
            $ops = array(
                'label' => $room->post_title,
                'value' => $room->ID,
                'calc' => 0,
                'selected' => false,
            );
        }
    
        // Add label option with instructions
        array_unshift($rooms, array(
            'label' => 'Select room...',
            'value' => '',
            'calc' => 0,
            'selected' => true
        ));

        $options = $opts;
    }

    return $options;
}, 10, 2);
```